# SignalR regular disconnection

Tags: signalr

**Environment**

- .NET MVC5
- IIS8.5 with websocket enabled
- IE11
- Windows 8.1
- SignalR 2.2.0

**Problem**

I've been running SignalR web application for two months, and I noticed a regular socket disconnection. I checked the console logs thoroughly and the result was quite surprising for me.

```
SCRIPT12030: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030
```

This happens regularly like below.

```
09 - 08:10:01
10 - 13:10:01
11 - 18:10:01
12 - 23:10:01
14 - 04:10:01
15 - 09:10:01
16 - 14:10:01
17 - 19:10:01
18 - 19:10:01
```

You can easily notice the 5 hours of interval and it happens only at 10:01. I already use `reconnecting`, `disconnected`, and `reconnected` callback to ensure the complete reconnection.

I have no special setting, just use default configuration. what could be the reason??

Comment: Can it be that there is a proxy or something on the way that is messing with the connection?

Comment: @Pawel Nope, the network is highly private, nothing messes it up.